# npm install cypress no_proxy not working (?)

Tags: angularjs, npm, npm-install, cypress, npm-scripts

my package.json file :

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "preinstall": "npm install --no-package-lock cross-env run-script-os rxjs && npm run install:cypress",
    "install:cypress:linux": "cross-env CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=https://internal.nexus.repo/cypress/4.4.1/cypress-4.4.1-linux-x64.zip npm install cypress@4.4.1 --save-exact",
    ...
  },
```

npm install  always trying to use http_proxy it seems, and apparently it fails, since its our internal repo doesn't need proxy. i added in no_proxy=.nexus.repo environment variable to bypass proxy.    I have proxy  configured in environment variables and also in .npmrc also. Looks like no_proxy option not working in this case ?     Any help us appreciated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue / workaround :  configured cntlm proxy , that able to bypass proxy for all the internal repos or all domains menioned in "noProxy" . just in case somebody is struggling with same issue  as above.

so in env :

```
export http_proxy = http:/10.0.0.10:3128 ( cntlm proxy)
```

in cntlm proxy :

```
 Proxy           http://corporateproxy     
 NoProxy         localhost, 127.0.0.*, .nexus.repo
```